# Acessar String em PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce

Boa tarde, 
estou usando a api do Woocommerce para automatizar meu site, porém estou tendo problemas quando tento acessar a resposta que ele envia quando cadastra o produto.
Envio a requisição para criar o produto, tudo normalmente, mas quero guardar o id do produto criado, para isso preciso percorrer a resposta, porém a resposta que chega está assim:

```html
public 'response' => 
        object(Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\Response)[8]
          private 'code' => int 201
          private 'headers' => 
            array (size=13)
              ...
          public 'body' => string '{"id":15286,"name":"Produto ABC","slug":"produto-abc-4","permalink":"https:\/\/hrconsultoria.com.br\/teste\/loja\/antartica\/produto-abc-4\/","date_created":"2020-01-31T15:05:18","date_created_gmt":"2020-01-31T18:05:18","date_modified":"2020-01-31T15:05:18","date_modified_gmt":"2020-01-31T18:05:18","type":"simple","status":"publish","featured":false,"catalog_visibility":"visible","description":"Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor qu'... (length=2801)
      private 'responseHeaders' => string
```

Quero acessar o id dentro de 'body', porém quando acesso assim:

```html
$teste = (array)$woocommerce->http->response->body;
```

O erro retornado é o: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object 
Tentei de outro modo:

```html
$teste = (array)$woocommerce->http->response->body;
print_r($teste[0]);
```

Mas dessa forma só exibe o '{' da string

Como posso percorrer essa string para obter o id do produto?

Comment: o conteúdo de body é um json, experimenta usar `json_decode($woocommerce->http->response->body, true);` para transformar em `array`.

Answer (score 0):

O conteúdo do body é uma string JSON. Pra acessar o ID, primeiro você precisa transformar essa string em um objeto:

```
$body = json_decode($data['response']['body']);
```

Agora, você consegue acessar qualquer propriedade do `body` assim:

```
echo $body->id; // Imprime o ID
echo $body->name; // Imprime o nome do produto
```